# VBA Print to PDF from a custom program

Tags: vba, ui-automation

At work we have a custom program that generates reports from our database.
We are not allowed to install new language packages or references, but I managed to automaticaly generate a report using excel's base UIAutomation, but this report needs to be saved as pdf in a directory, as one would do it they hit CTRL+P and selected the printer name as "Microsoft Print to PDF". Is there any way to automate this step using only VBA?

If it is of any help, my code is as follows:

```
Sub open_evol()
Dim oUIAutomation As New CUIAutomation8
Dim oUIADesktop As IUIAutomationElement
Dim allChilds As IUIAutomationElementArray
Dim allChildsAxys As IUIAutomationElementArray
Dim axys As IUIAutomationElement
Dim axys2 As IUIAutomationElement
Dim intermed As IUIAutomationElement
Dim boxes As IUIAutomationElementArray
Dim boxes2 As IUIAutomationElementArray
Dim a As IUIAutomationElement


Set oUIADesktop = oUIAutomation.GetRootElement

Debug.Print oUIADesktop.CurrentName

Set allChilds = oUIADesktop.FindAll(TreeScope_Children, oUIAutomation.CreateTrueCondition)

For i = 0 To allChilds.Length - 1
    Debug.Print i & ":=" & allChilds.GetElement(i).CurrentName & vbTab & allChilds.GetElement(i).CurrentClassName
    If Left(allChilds.GetElement(i).CurrentName, 12) = "Axys Reports" Then
    Set axys = allChilds.GetElement(i)
    End If
Next

On Error GoTo escape:
axys.SetFocus
On Error GoTo 0

SendKeys "%cee~", True

time1 = Now
time2 = Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Do Until time1 >= time2
        DoEvents
        time1 = Now()
    Loop

Set allChildsAxys = axys.FindAll(TreeScope_Children, oUIAutomation.CreateTrueCondition)

Set axys2 = allChildsAxys.GetElement(0)
Set boxes = axys2.FindAll(TreeScope_Element, oUIAutomation.CreateTrueCondition)

For i = 0 To boxes.Length - 1
    If Left(boxes.GetElement(i).CurrentName, 8) = "Evol e R" Then
    Set intermed = boxes.GetElement(i)
    Debug.Print "intermet: "; boxes.GetElement(i).CurrentName
    End If
Next i

Set boxes2 = intermed.FindAll(TreeScope_Subtree, oUIAutomation.CreateTrueCondition)

boxes2.GetElement(4).SetFocus

SendKeys "+^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT} +^{LEFT}", True
SendKeys "{DELETE}", True
SendKeys "@5ABE2", True

boxes2.GetElement(9).SetFocus

SendKeys "^{RIGHT} +^{LEFT}", True
SendKeys "{DELETE}", True
SendKeys "033118", True

boxes2.GetElement(13).SetFocus

SendKeys "^{RIGHT} +^{LEFT}", True
SendKeys "{DELETE}", True
SendKeys "043018", True

boxes2.GetElement(26).SetFocus

SendKeys "{ENTER}"

End


escape:
MsgBox ("Open Axys Reports")

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you looking just to save the file as pdf at the end of your script?  You could use something like: 

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Comment: @JosephMason it's not totally clear from OP's question, but this is not a question about exporting an Excel worksheet to PDF. OP is using Excel only as an IDE, within which to automate some external application.

Comment: What's the purpose of things like `"%cee~"` and `"@5ABE2"`? Are these *commands* you're sending to the other application?

Comment: Also, probably helpful if you would indicate clearly *what* application you're trying to automate. Perhaps there is an API (doubtful, but possible there's one you don't know about), or perhaps there's a `SendKeys` hack you can use like the rest of your function.

Comment: sorry for the delay, yes "%cee~" is me navigating the context menu to open and generate the report and "@5ABE2" is the report i want to generate, this would be my parameter when I call this function.

I want to automate the print to pdf of an external application, not of an worksheet. Is there any way that I could check for an available dialoguebox or some way of interacting with an existing "print" menu using direct commands, not sendkeys?

Comment: only if this application has an API. since you still haven't indicated what applicant you're using, nobody can answer that for you lol.

Comment: It's na old application for cashflow databases, called Axis. I am not capable of using the documentation on the context of VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> is the appropriate hotkey in your custom application to open up the print dialog, you might be able to hack it with `SendKeys`.

```
Dim filename as String
filename = "c:/path/to/my filename" ' do not need to include the .PDF extension

' Open the print dialog
SendKeys "^p", True
' Select your printer (this may not be necessary, but since we don't know
' anything about your application or what it's print dialog looks like, 
' you'll have to probably make some changes 
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
' Once the printer has been selected, send the filename to the dialog
SendKeys filename, True
' Sending ENTER again should execute the Print to PDF
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

**Note** This assumes that "Microsoft Print to PDF" is the default printer. If that is not the case, and your application doesn't provide an API, there's probably still a way to do this using `FindWindow`/etc and other more complicated `WinAPI` calls.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, could you point me to some direction that I could find out how to do this with WinApi calls or some other way? Using sendkeys to do this would not be optimal, as the macro needs to generate about 500 reports and save them as pdf.

Comment: This procedure was done until now by hand, it would take an analyst about 3h of worktime to do this and it needs to be done every week. The program we use is called axys, as we are an old institution I am not able to install anything on my machine, so my options are very limited when it comes to automation...

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Windows-API/WIN32APITXTWin32APIDeclarationsforVisualBasic.htm. you'll probably need to start with FindWindow and get the window's handle. there's plenty of questions here which could point you in the right direction to start

Comment: it's unlikely you'll be able to do it all without send keys, you'll probably require a combination of that and winapi and tbh there's no way to help you figure oot how to interact with an application that I don't have and which doesn't have sn api, unfortunately.

Comment: that's alright, i think it will be more than enought to do some improvements comparing to the current procedure, thank you very much for the help!